# How to convert HTML codes to XAML in Windows Phone

Tags: html, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I am creating Windows Phone Application, I am getting HTML codes from web service response,
like

```
"&nbsp;,<br>"
```

how do I convert them in xaml?
is there any static method available?

because I have tried HttpUtility mehtod but not getting the converted result

Comment: Where are you trying to display the text? What types of HTML elements are being returned?

Comment: @WiredPrairie I am displaying text in listbox, I am getting "&nbsp;" and "<br>"..so which static method is eligible?

Comment: You could just use a string replace to remove those.

Comment: @WiredPrairie but there could be plenty of HTML codes, then what should I do?

Comment: Look for the HTML Agility Pack (and specifically one that works with WP8). It has some features that you might find useful to scrub the HTML.

Comment: @WiredPrairie ok, thanks man,I shall check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use this HTML to XAML FlowDocument converter: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/05/25/606317.aspx

Then you could use a custom control, here's an example:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ReplyBoxControl}">
   <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="#F0E0D6" MaxHeight="320" Width="300">
         <FlowDocumentScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="320" Height="Auto"
Document="{TemplateBinding TestText2, Converter={StaticResource HtmlToFlowDocumentConverter}}" />
   </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in functionality to do this. You'll need to manually map the content to a [`<RichTextBox />`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and insert the necessary `<Paragraph />` and `<Run />` elements as necessary.

Comment: thanks for quick reply but I have to display contents in a listBox then how to solve? can you show me some code or example??

Comment: You'll have to add multiple RichTextBox elements to your ListBox if necessary. The MSDN provides fine examples of how to construct a RichTextBox.